# Generalizing the rearrangement inequality

Tags: inequality

I had recently solved a problem in which we had to prove that:

> $2\sqrt{(x+y)(a+b)}\ge \sqrt{xa}+\sqrt{yb}+\sqrt{xb}+\sqrt{ya}$.

I proved this by using Cauchy-Scwartz twice and summing up the results. But I was wondering whether we could use the following method.

Step 1: Apply Cauchy-Scwartz once and double it.

Step 2: Use the rearrangement inequality by assuming WLOG $a>b$ and $x>y$ and write $\sqrt{xa}+\sqrt{yb}>\sqrt{xb}+\sqrt{ya}$ using the similar reasoning as the proof of rearrangement inequality. (Ref: Problem solving strategies by Arthur Engel)

Furthermore, can the above logic be generalized for all increasing functions? It seems intuitive but I'm not able to prove it.

Comment: MathJax tip: curly braces { } are how you "group" things in MathJax. For example `$\sqrt(x + y)$` will just put the square root over the next character: the $($. But, if you put `$\sqrt{x + y}$` instead, you get $\sqrt{x + y}$, i.e. the square root is over everything contained in the curly braces.

Comment: You can also use means: $HM_{1/2}(xa,ya,xb,yb)\le AM(xa,ya,xb,yb)$.

Comment: @Theo Bendit Thank you! But is the logic of generalizing correct?

Comment: No, the generalization to all increasing functions doesn't hold. EG take $ f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: Another approach is to show that $ \sqrt{2} \sqrt{x+y} \geq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$ (EG by squaring), then multiply with the similar inequality.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Thank you so much!